# Proof for the ratio test - unclear question special case

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence with $a_n>0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$.

Prove that the series $\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, if $\alpha>1$ and $n_0\in \Bbb N$ such that $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\le1-\frac{\alpha}{n}$$ for all $n>n_0$. Also prove that the series diverges if $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\ge1-\frac{1}{n}$

I am not quite sure how to prove this, can someone give me a hint? The $\alpha$ here, what is it for? Does

Comment: $\alpha >1$ is to avoid the situation in the "prove that the series diverges ..." line that follows

Comment: @Henry cann you give me a hint on how to solve the problem?

Comment: This is Raabe's test.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests you consider $\lim \inf n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)$ for the first part and then compare to $\sum 1/n^R$.  I suspect here $\lim \inf n\left(1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)$ might be easier to start with